# f2py installation not working under Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, fortran, f2py

I am using Python 3.2 under Windows 7.  I need some numerical subroutines for my Python script, and I would like to write them in Fortran and use f2py to make them compatible with my script.

As per the [f2py documentation](http://www.scipy.org/F2py), I installed numpy (v1.6.1), then tried running `f2py` on the command line to check the installation.  Windows keeps telling me that "f2py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file."  I tried adding "C:\Python32\Scripts" to my PATH, but that didn't help.  (C:\Python32 is my Python installation directory, and is also in my PATH, numpy is also installed here)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run `f2py.py`. If you want to omit the .py extension, add `.PY` to your `PATHEXT` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the `PATHEXT` tip!

Comment: I am having the same issue but other .py files in Scripts, like pip, are running fine without the extension. Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: @Chris, automatically created script "entry points" are installed using EXE wrappers, such as pip.exe. This wrapper executes the fully-qualified path of python.exe with a small embedded script that imports the package and calls the given entry-point function. OTOH, pre-written scripts don't get EXE wrappers. Running them depends on the "Scripts" directory being in `PATH`; optionally (required in PowerShell) ".PY" being in `PATHEXT`; and the .PY file association being  correctly configured.

Comment: @eryksun This makes sense, I didn't consider that pip.exe was being run instead of pip.py. Thanks for the explanation. -C

Answer (score 1):

In 2016, you should be able to run `f2py` as an executable numpy module from the command line:

`python -m numpy.f2py`

This avoids needing to mess around with environment variables, and works on my Windows machine with numpy 1.10.4.

(Further discussion: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5565, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7532)

Answer (score 0):

did you try f2py.py ? or "python f2py.py" or "python f2py"? depending on the file and if you have windows use python to open py ext files